# Keras: What if i recompile my model after training few epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, model-fitting

I have a model and i want to train it with learning_rate = 0.8 for few epochs,  then set learning rate = 0.4 & continue training.
But as learning rate is being set when compiling model... So what will happen to model/weights if i recompile it after few epochs?

Below is my code: P.S (my learning rate is dynamic)

```
lr = 0.04
adam = Adam(lr=lr)
weight_factor = 10
models.compile(
    optimizer=adam,
"kullback_leibler_divergence"
    loss = {'W1':kl_divergence,'age':mae},
    metrics={"age": mae,"W1":'accuracy'},
    loss_weights={'W1':weight_factor, 'age': 1}
)
```

dynamic learning rate Callbacks

```
callbacks = [
  ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_age_mean_absolute_error', 
                    factor = 0.5, 
                    patience = 7,
                    min_delta = 0.01, 
                    cooldown = 2,
                    min_lr = 0.0001,
                    mode = 'min')
]
```

Training

```
epochs=35
history = models.fit(train_gen, steps_per_epoch=len(trainset) / batch_size, epochs=epochs, callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=validation_gen, validation_steps=len(testset) / batch_size * 3)
```

Comment: My findings: When i train few eopchs with lr=0.8, then recompile with lr= 0.4 & start training.... My model does not improve more.

Answer (score 3):

when you recompile model you weights are reset to random.

so you should save weights using `model.save_weights('weights.h5')` then compile model, after which load weights `model.load_weights('weights.h5')`

Comment: Recompiling is nothing to do with model weights. Your first statement is wrong.

Comment: model.compile has nothing to do with weight resets, @Innat is correct here